# Why does this AJAX success callback never run?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been stuck 2 days on the **TutsPlus - jQuery in 30 Days** exercises... lesson 26

Why does my ajax success function refuse to log the results to the console?
What happens instead is index.php simply echoes the text onto the webpage itself.
It's like some syntax problem is preventing the success callback from even running at all.
The rest of the code works (it does not rely on this particular callback), but I don't want to proceed until I find out what's wrong.

```
 var Actors = {
    init: function( config ) {
        this.config = config;
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        this.config.letterSelection.on('change', this.fetchActors);
    },

    fetchActors: function() {
        var self = Actors;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: self.config.form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(results) {
                console.log(results);
            }
        });

    }
 };

 Actors.init({
    letterSelection: $('#q'),
    form: $('#actor-selection')
 })
```

and here's my index.php page...

```
<?php

require 'functions.php';

if ( isset($_POST['q']) ) {
    connect();

    $actors = get_actors_by_last_name( $_POST['q'] );

    echo 'index returning your call with ' . $_POST['q'];
    // echo json_encode($actors); return; 
}

include 'views/index.tmpl.php';

?>
```

Comment: Add an `error` callback as well and log what's returned. Most likely the call is failing, possible due to a PHP scripting error on your server. View the console while you're at it by pressing `<F12>`...

Comment: When expecting `dataType: 'json'`, the entire response needs to be a single JSON value. With `echo 'index returning ...`', the response won't be valid JSON.

Comment: ok here is some wisdom and I'm back on track - thanks! (why not post it as an answer though?)

Comment: Change your dataType (in your AJAX function) to HTML if you're going to echo out something like "index...."

Comment: This question is not worth keeping. May I suggest deletion?

Comment: @Jan you have my vote.

Comment: close it - but who benefits from the down votes? @Jan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying a `dataType`, such as `'json'`, the entire response needs to conform to that type.

By including additional output, such as:

```
echo 'index returning your call with ' . $_POST['q'];
```

The response won't be valid JSON and jQuery will `error` when attempting to parse it.